# Simple nginx error but I am blind it feels like

Tags: nginx

This is my config as of now, trying to set this site up with ssl certificate.

```
server {

        listen [::]:443 ssl domain.io, *.domain.io;

        ssl    on;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/domain.io.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/certs/domain.io.key;

        root /var/www/html/domain.io/;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html;

        server_name domain.io;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}
```

When I restart nginx it complains about this:
nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "domain.io," in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain.io:3

What am I missing? I am for the moment config-blind. :)

Sp be kind I toting out my dead simple error.

Trying to see what simple error I have made and failed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see listen directive accepting a domain name.

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/web-server/

I would try this:

```
    server {

        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        ssl    on;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/domain.io.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/certs/domain.io.key;

        root /var/www/html/domain.io/;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html;

        server_name domain.io *.domain.io;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}
```